# gwt module does not load on gae

Tags: gwt

on a particular page on our site http://www.sakshum.org/ui/page/JoinUs.jsp which is build using gwt and deployed on GAE the module does not load.

This works fine in development env in eclipse and have no errors when looking via firebug in the console.

Please advise what may be wrong here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the help. So, the issue was completely different. Actually the div tag was not rendering at all due to the coding error of a if statement in the jsp. On fixing that it started working

Answer (score 1):

look at the AE logs.  firebug will only show you client side stuff.  It's probably a classpath issue -- such as you have something locally but aren't uploading that jar ...etc.

**Edit:**

please post your JoinUs.jsp

I am calling my gwt module via a jsp page on AE no problem.  Maybe the path in your script tag pointing to the *.nocache.jsp file is off somehow.  Usually when things resolve locally but not on AE, for me, the problem was appengine-web.xml and setting include and exclude paths.  I had to be careful there because things worked differently locally and deployed - especially using wildcard.

Also, look for uri errors under the dashboard (ae administration page).  static resources that are not found will show there and not in the ae log since they are static.

Comment: i dont see anything in AE logs as well /2012-09-06 16:09:15.426 /ui/page/JoinUs.jsp 200 26ms 8kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1255.0 Safari/537.8
148.87.19.194 - - [06/Sep/2012:16:09:15 -0700] "GET /ui/page/JoinUs.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 8136 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1255.0 Safari/537.8" "www.sakshum.org" ms=26 cpu_ms=47 cpm_usd=0.000909 instance=00c61b117c71dc4a3eb8362d8a4164784d1d548e

Comment: @Vik please see my edits -- maybe a static resource is not being found

Comment: but how do i find which one is not available?

Comment: @Vik look for uri errors under the dashboard (ae administration page). static resources that are not found will show there and not in the ae log since they are static.